# drawRect and AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, drawrect

I'm using the following code

```
      self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
  [self.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile-image-placeholder"]];
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
```

but in drawRect can't see the image only the placeholder using the following

```
[self.imageView.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(15.0f, 5.0f)];
```

any ideas on this?

Comment: You are aware that the remote image will be available to your imageView after it has been downloaded which will not be immediately after setting up the image-view with its URL?

Comment: I am using my answer with success.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is this.  AFNetworking will cancel the image operation if the cell is reused so you don't need to worry about that edge case.

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile-image-placeholder"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
      self.imageview.image=image;
      [self setNeedsLayout];
      [self setNeedsDisplay];

    } failure:nil];
```